# Android-passing string from one activity to another activity is not working,

Tags: java, android, sms

I want to pass one string variable from one activity to another activity,but is not working for me,i want to send the string from Main activity to sendsms activity.The sending string should be set in sms message part.

Main activity.java

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Retrive Data from list
        for (Application bean : items) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(Html.fromHtml(bean.getContent()));
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showAlertView(String str) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            alert.setTitle("Not Selected");
            alert.setMessage("No One is Seleceted!!!");
        } else {
            // Remove , end of the name


            alert.setTitle("Selected");
            alert.setMessage(strContactList);
        }
        alert.setButton("sms", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //sendSMS();
                /*Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", strContactList); 
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(sendIntent);*/
                Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendSMSActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("firstkeyName", strContactList);
                startActivity(intent1);

            }


        });
```

from main activity to send an string  to sendsmsactivity.java

sendsmsactivity.java

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;
    String sms;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
             sms = extras.getString("firstkeyName");
        }
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
              try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the sendsmsactivity, i want to get the string from main activity and it has to set as sms body of the send sms activity.i want to do like that,but right now my code is not working ,its not getting the string from main to sendsmsactivity.

Comment: sms = extras.getString("firstKeyName"); shoudl be  sms = extras.getString("firstkeyName"); keys should match .you had capital K for your key in sendsmsactivity.java while in mainactivity you have intent1.putExtra("firstkeyName", strContactList);

Comment: copy your key from putExtra() and paste into getString();

Comment: Dude,i correct that one also,eventhough its not fetching,there i put sms = extras.... like that,and here smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null); i put like this,this is correct want to add anyother codes @Raghunandan

Comment: did u Log ur String before putting into intent?

Comment: @Naser,ya i copied like that in my mainactivity intent1.putExtra("firstKeyName", strContactList); and sendsmsactivity its like that Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras !=null) {
       sms = extras.getString("firstKeyName");
  }

Comment: check your ' strContactList ' variable before send to other activity. it can be empty string . also try creating new string as using strContactList. cuz it is final string. android may restrict sending final variables.

Comment: @Naser,how to log my string,and why i want to do that one

Comment: @KarthickM check if strContactList is null or not

Comment: @user1645941, ok dude if i remove the final in that place,its showing error intent1.putExtra("firstKeyName", strContactList);error like this Cannot refer to a non-final variable strContactList inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Log.d("test","strContactList: "+strContactList); call this before intent.

Comment: @Naser   In which place i have to write that code,and for what purpose

Comment: @Karthick M really?u dont know where to put Log.

Comment: before putextra code we have toput,i am new thats why i asked you,why we want to use,tell me @Naser

Comment: @user1645941, if i remove the final it will work ,but if i remove the final how could i solve the problem

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: use your debugger Luke

Comment: @Naser ok what to do now to solve my error

Comment: @KarthickM declare this strContactList as a class variable and use the same if you don't want final modifier. but check if the string you pass is null or not.

Comment: @Raghunandan, now what to do dude,to solve this issure

Comment: check if strContactList  is null or not.

Comment: no dude its not null i am sure in that one@Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM do you get any erros or exceptions if so post the stack trace. if it's not null it should work

Comment: its not fetching data,and its not showing that string in strcontact list value in message body of sms,now its empty@Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM if the key matches and your value that you pass is not null it should work. cross check again.

Comment: the key is we will give anything na,bit it should be same only na dude,i put the same thing also eventhough its not showing anything in the messagebody@Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM try this if(strContactList!=null){Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendSMSActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("firstkeyName", strContactList);
                startActivity(intent1);}. coz i don't see anything wrong and i guess strContactList is null

Comment: @Raghunandan, same thing its going to smsactivity,but in message body its not displaying the content of strcontactlist

Comment: why dont you debug
SendSMSActivity?

Comment: @KarthickM i can't think of any other reason. i don't see anything wrong with the code. i don't think i can help you further

Comment: for what  i want to do@pskink

Comment: @Raghunandan, can you see myboth sms and mainactivity code,its ok

Comment: @KarthickM try this  in your sms activity  if(extras !=null) {
             sms = extras.getString("firstkeyName");textSMS.setText(sms);
        } check if something is displayed in textview

Comment: just set two breakpoints: where you setting the extra and where you getting the extra and run the debugger

Comment: Dude i dont know its also not working cant judge where the problem@Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM String n = new String(strContactList); intent.putExtra('firstKeyName',n);

Comment: @user1645941, i got solution dude,now i wants that fetch from contacts in my phone,but here i want to type manually in my phone,how to do that one

Comment: @KarthickM developer.android.com

Comment: @user1645941,what there is no link dude,how to do that contact in edit text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for your question, give it a try...

```
Intent intent1= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
final String firstKeyName = intent1.getStringExtra("firstKeyName");
textSMS.setText(firstKeyName);
```

Change your Onclick function like this

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, firstKeyName, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo is your extras. Try using "firstkeyName". It should work. Something like :

```
sms = extras.getString("firstkeyName");
```

Comment: Dude i put like that only,can you look at my code

Comment: You could try hard-coding your strContactList to ABCD and check. This would ensure that the string is ! null.

Comment: string is not null i am sure that,but i have one doubt i put final that may create problem

Comment: why do you think it would ?

Comment: why dont you debug SendSMSActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You had firstkeyName and firstKeyName two different key names. i.e. k is capital in first activity. 
Just make it as a constant & access it from both activities.

Comment: no its not pblm,i changed and check that one also

Comment: did you try using debug mode ? also check using String smsString getIntent().getStringExtra("firstkeyName"); whether is it null or any other string ?

Comment: its not fetching data from one activity to another activity

Comment: @Karthick try following code in OnCreate() of first activity. Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendSMSActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("firstkeyName", "hardcodedString");
                startActivity(intent1); & then check to other activity.

Comment: try it on debug mode so that will get clear idea. as per above code mention try to call sms activity from oncreate() of first activity.

Comment: @chaitanaya,this same code only i put,but you put as "hardcodeed string",why,but i need strContactList,this only having my values

Comment: @KarthickM you can just try by using it. If it is successful will go with next steps. Also, you can check the values of strContactList before this line intent1.putExtra("firstkeyName", strContactList); There is chances of null or empty value string.

Comment: @chatianya,i checked there is no null exception there,could you give your gmail id,i will send my code to you

Comment: send your code on deshmukhcv@gmail.com. I will check it

Comment: ya i send my code can you check it and accept my request in gtalk,my id is karthickbe2008@gmail.com

Comment: have u got my mail@chaitanya

Comment: yes received u r mail. checking for same

Comment: the issue is resolved... The problem is with your  final String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1); key

Comment: just add one string member variable in class not in method & assign the final string value to it. & you can directly access it in class.

Comment: if you need code let me know

Comment: Dude i got solution,thanks the lot for guiding me.for send number its getting only number from me why its not going to myphone contact

Comment: Dude i got solution,thanks the lot for guiding me.for send number its getting only number from me why its not going to myphone contact

Comment: " for send number its getting only number from me why its not going to myphone contact " what you want here ? to display the phones contact in edit box ? or some thing else

Comment: display phone contact in edit box,phone number

Comment: i want to dispaly phone contacts in my edit box,i dont wants to type manuall number there

Comment: i dont wants to type manually phone number,i want to get phone number from my contact,how to do in  my code dude

Comment: @chatianya, are you there dude,how to get the phone contacts to my edit box,full not if i click there it has to go to my contacts from there i have to take whatever i need